# How to optimize the app for 10 inch tablet?

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to optimize my application for the 10 inch tablet. I have done some research and found out that if we add the below two lines to the images the images scale up keeping the aspect ratio same. The trick is doing fine until 8 inch tablet but the images are again getting distorted for 10 inch tablet.

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

what can be the possible steps to optimise?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is distorted because of the scaleType="fitXY" which will cause the image to alter its aspect ratio to adjust to the boundary of the imageview. On the otherhand adjustviewbounds will make the imageview adjust to the provided image(any image you show) and maintain its aspect ratio. This two property dont mix well. So please decide which one is more important and keep it and remove the other. More on the developers website [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

Comment: Hi, i want that the image should keep the aspect ratio and fill the entire width

Comment: that is preety tricky in android if the image is big then both width set to match parent and height set to wrap content is enough but if you need it with a smaller image you cannot get that effect see here http://etcodehome.blogspot.it/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html for different property variations in andoroid